# probability of circuit operations

Tags: probability

An electrical circuit is composed of 5 units connected according to the diagram.
The probability that each unit is functional is p, and there is no correlation between the functionality of the different units.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFJfi.png)

A. What is the probability that the circuit operates?

B. If it is known that the circuit operates, what is the expected number of functional units?

C. Now assume that unit C is replaced by a new unit 'C', with the probability of being functional being q. What is the probability that the new circuit (after the replacement) operates, given that the original circuit operated

to be honest thats new subject for me if someone can shed some light on the steps to solve it id be thankful.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It doesn't work if A does not work AND B does not work. When else does it not work? Combine those none working conditions with OR. Use the basic probability laws for AND and OR to work out the probability the system does not work.

Comment: To be clear, is the thing you're having trouble with the probability part or the circuit part?

Comment: the probability part